# Sell a Silverlight Out of Browser Application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a Silverlight Out of Browser (OOB) Application that I created in my spare time and would like to sell on the Web. The only difference between the paid and the free version would be that the free version is ad supported.

So my questions are:

1. Can a Silverlight OOB application be sold? Any sample of a commercial Silverlight OOB out there?
2. Can a Silverlight OOB application include ads? I would like something similar to what I see in the free version of [Download Accelerator Plus](http://speedbit.com).
3. Which is the modern standard/secure way of selling Windows desktop apps these days? I was thinking in requiring an activation code from my users, which I would somehow generate/validate from a server.
4. Which is the easiest/simplest way to get the infrastructure to sell my app? I have zero budget, any infrastructure to sell the app should not cost anything to me, although I could host a free open source e-commerce site if required.